# Montar uma imagem a partir de outras imagens com PHP

Tags: php, imagem, gd

Olá;

Gostaria de saber se consigo montar uma imagem a partir de outras imagens de forma sequencial.

Por exemplo: Digamos que tenho um cadastro de palavras e imagens definidas para cada letra do alfabeto. Ao cadastrar uma palavra, Abelha por exemplo, quero criar uma imagem a partir de 6 imagens(A B E L H A). **Obs:** Não quero dar uma imagecreate a partir de uma string, quero criar a partir de imagens já definidas.

**Solução**

```
$string = "ABELHA";
$len = strlen($string);
$im = imagecreatetruecolor( 60 * $len, 60 );
for( $i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i ) {
    $letra = substr( $string, $i, 1 );
    $lim= imagecreatefrompng("./$letra.png");
    imagecopy ( $im, $lim, $i * 60, 0, 0, 0, 60, 60 );
    imagedestroy( $lim );
}
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg( $im );
imagedestroy( $im );
```

Comment: Oi Bacco, nessa situação em específico eu não tentei nada ainda, já gerei imagem a partir de um texto por exemplo (captcha), mas não dessa forma como descrevi. Pesquisei os comandos de imagem no PHP e o que achei foram comandos que mesclam imagem basicamente, por isso queria saber se é possível.

Comment: Praticamente fiz o essencial pra você, e postei como resposta. Claro que vai precisar de ajustes, mas o essencial está lá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua pergunta é um pouco ampla, mas segue um código base:

Suponhamos que as letras tenham tamanho 60×60px e salvas como `A.png`, `B.png` etc.

```
$string = 'ABELHA';
$len = count( $string );
$im = imagecreatetruecolor( 60 * $len, 60 );
for( $i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i ) {
   $letra = ( $string, $i, 1 );
   $lim= imagecreatefrompng("/caminho/$letra.png");
   imagecopy ( $im, $lim, $i * 60, 0, 0, 0, 60, 60 );
   imagedestroy( $lim );
}
imagejpeg( $im );
imagedestroy( $im );
```

Pus o foco no problema da pergunta, não considerei problemas de encoding e acentuação, nem caracteres especiais para não estender demais.

Para usar outros caracteres sem ser números e de A a Z, tem que tratar a string da forma que achar mais adequado.

Comment: Hmm, show de bola, vou fazer um teste com o seu exemplo.

Comment: @Reji provavelmente vai esbarrar em alguma bobeira de sintaxe, ou algum erro nas coordenadas, mas acho que se você ler no manual do PHP as funções, arruma fácil. Mas qualquer coisa, comente. Eu fiz o código direto aqui na resposta sem testar, pode ter passado algo.

Comment: Pra falar bem a verdade, segui sua pergunta, mas eu acho que seria muito mais eficiente uma imagem só com todas as letras, e recortar dela para a imagem de saída, em vez delas salvas em separado.

Comment: Acertou na mosca, exatamente o que eu queria fazer. Valeu mesmo, é porque eu tinha que definir que da pra fazer isso mas não estou com muito tempo pra ver se era possível, achei que teria que usar algum comando mirabolante.  De fato uma imagem só seria mais fácil, mas eu não terei letras de saída, serão sinais, por isso a necessidade ;)